# Catalina 10.15 removing Spotlight icon from menu bar went wrong

Tags: mac, macos-catalina, spotlight

I’ve done csrutil disable and went into Terminal and put

cd /System/Library/CoreServices
sudo mv Search.bundle/ Search2.bundle/

I rebooted and it removed the Spotlight icon from the menu bar but I could no longer use command-R to open Spotlight. I tried undoing via

sudo mv Search2.bundle/ Search.bundle/

but it returns

mv: rename Search2.bundle/ to Search.bundle/: Read-only file system.

Rebooted but still no functioning Spotlight. What can I do?

Comment: When I try to use sudo chmod 666 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search it returns chmod: /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the OS from Recovery.
It should restore any missing or corrupt system files whilst leaving user data untouched.